# Sharepoint Farm - direct requests as specific servers

Tags: architecture, server-farm

We have a Sharepoint Farm with 3 WFE.
We have a number of Web Applications on the Sharepoint Farm.
Is it possible that for one web application we always redirect all requests to a single WFE?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your web application has a seperate host header, then just point the DNS directly to that WFE instead of going through your load balancer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thout there could be some sharepoint settings that allows you do this. but it makes sense to set it at the DNS level